# How can I use a generic type inside the state or props type for a react component?

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```
class Fetcher<T> extends React.Component<FetcherProps & { other: T }, FetcherState> {
  constructor(props: FetcherProps & { other: T }) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

Except in the actual code, the type declaration is a lot larger than just `{ other: T }`, to the extent that it destroys readability. It's for react render props-- i'm trying to generically type the data passed to the child component.

Is there any way to use `T` in the props type for a component when it's complex and nested like this?

For reference, the code actually looks like this:

```
class Fetcher<T> extends React.Component<FetcherProps & { children: (props: {data: T | null, reload: any, error: any, isLoading: boolean}) => React.ReactNode }, FetcherState> {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a generic type in addition to the generic component, and pass the generic type through. So instead of `FetcherProps & { other: T }`, I went with this:

```
type FetcherProps<T> = {
   /* non-generic property types omitted */
   other: T;
};
```

Then you declare the class as:

`class Fetcher<T> extends React.Component<FetcherProps<T>, FetcherState> {`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
type Props<T> = FetcherProps & { children: (props: {data: T | null, reload: any, error: any, isLoading: boolean}) => React.ReactNode };

class Fetcher<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>, FetcherState> {
  constructor(props: Props<T>) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```